# Conditionally triggering click event function in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an Angular 2 application that has a table with checkboxes in a column.  When a user clicks a checkbox, a modal will appear with more details about that row.  However, I only want to show the modal if the checkbox is checked.  Here is what I have now:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of searchItems">
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="rowCheckbox" (click)="setSelectedRow(item);modal.show();" /></td>
 ...

</tr>
```

Can I apply a condition to `modal.show()`?  Something like `if(this['checked']){modal.show();};`?

Comment: you can define template variable #myChekbox and then you can do mycheckbox.value && model.show();

Comment: @fastAsTortoise It seems that it stills hows the modal even if I uncheck the checkbox :/

Comment: you can pass  your modal to function too and do modal.show() in your setSelectedRow funtion or get the reference of the modal in your component somehow and do your show in logic there.

Comment: @fastAsTortoise It worked by putting it in the function!  So, I actually found the issue that myCheckbox.value would always return true, and this['checked'] would always return false.  I just had to change it to myCheckbox.checked

Comment: There you go. Please upvote the comments if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Import the FormsModule into the component's module, add a checked: boolean variable to your component class and then change your input like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked" name="rowCheckbox" (click)="setSelectedRow(item); checked ? modal.show() : '';" /></td>
```

You can't use an if statement in Angular's expressions but you can use ternary operations.